# How can I pipe a docker ps output to a docker stop command?

Tags: bash, docker, grep

I want to stop all containers that have `dev1102`in their name. There are several containers but I never know how many. So I run `docker ps |grep -o 'dev1102_[A-Za-z\_]*'` which lists me all containers I need. Output looks like this

```
dev1102_abc_de
dev1102_admin
dev1102_app_qqq
```

How can I pipe this output into a docker stop command, so all the listed containers from the grep get stopped?
I tried `docker stop < docker ps |grep -o 'dev1102_[A-Za-z\_]*'` but that results in a bash error:

*`-bash: docker: No such file or directory`*

Comment: I noticed my Grep only captures dev1102_..... but I actually want all containers with dev1102, so also dev1102-xx-x and dev1102morecontainters. Whats the correct regEx ?

Answer (score 1):

`docker stop $(docker ps | grep -o 'dev1102_[A-Za-z\_]*')`

should do the job!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to pass the the output of `docker ps | grep -o 'dev1102_[A-Za-z\_]*'` to `docker stop` command with `xargs` like this:

`docker ps | grep -o 'dev1102_[A-Za-z\_]*' | xargs -I {} docker stop {}`

Here `xargs -I {} docker stop {}` placeholder `{}` is replaced by each container name.

Comment: great. thanks. And how can I expand the regex to show me all containers that have '1102' inside their name, e.g. dev1102abc, abc_1102-more, mycont-1102_db etc

Comment: `grep '1102'` will give all records with `1102` substring.

Comment: doesnt work. Gives me error "error from daemon" no such container 1102

Comment: This will get only container names and grep them with 1102: `docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' | grep '1102' | xargs -I {} docker stop {}`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use restructured, new syntax of [Docker CLI commands](https://www.docker.com/blog/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/) introduced in Docker 1.13. E.g. use `docker container ls` with `filter` flag, it is clean and more readable:

```bash
docker container stop $(docker container ls --all --quiet --filter "name=^dev1102_[A-Za-z\_]*")
```

If you want to get container names with `docker container ls` use `--format "{{.Names}}"` instead of `--quiet`.

Comment: great. thanks. And how can I expand the regex to show me all containers that have '1102' inside their name, e.g. dev1102abc, abc_1102-more, mycont-1102_db etc

Comment: Just use different regex pattern to e.g. match your container name containing '1102'. See and test here: https://regex101.com/r/cPUoDi/1

Comment: Thanks /.*1102.*/ works. 
The command you are proposing only prints the docker ID. Can you show the container name and also show containers that are not running?

Comment: It returns docker IDs as `docker stop` needs it to stop containers by IDs. If you want to list all containers including exited one use `docker container ls --all`

Comment: docker can start/stop by container name. I dont want to use IDs as I want to visually check I am stopping the right ones. How can ls output container names?

Comment: `docker container stop $(docker container ls --all --filter "name=.*1102.*" --format "{{.Names}}")`  will get containers matching regex pattern and stop docker containers by matched names. But stopping by container ID is more rebust.